# SQL with WITH clause too many values error

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sqlplus, with-statement

--This query is returning a "too many values" error. I'm not sure why?

```
   update myTable
            set var1= var2
            WHERE value1 IN (

             WITH X AS
            (
            select value1, value2, var1,var2, ROW_NUMBER()
            OVER
            (PARTITION BY value1 ORDER BY value1 desc) as rn
            from
              mytable WHERE var1 is null AND rownum>0 and rownum<=10 order by value1 asc
            )
            SELECT
            value1, value2, var2,var1
           FROM X WHERE rn=1  and var1 is null and rownum>0 and rownum<=10);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `too many values` is because the query has `value1 IN ()` where multiple columns are being selected in the inner query. To avoid this, just `select` value1 in the inner query.

```
update myTable
set var1 = var2
WHERE value1 IN
     (select value1 from 
       (select value1, value2, var1,var2, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY value1 ORDER BY value1 desc) as rn
        from mytable 
        WHERE var1 is null
        ) t 
      where rn <= 10
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your intention is better served using `exists`:

```
update myTable
    set var1 = var2
    where exists (select 1
                  from (select value1, value2, var1, var2, 
                               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY value1 ORDER BY value1 desc) as rn
                       from mytable 
                       where var1 is null
                      ) x
                  where mytable.value1 in (x.value1, x.value2, x.var1, x.var2) and
                        rn <= 10
                 );
```